# Function Composition in R (and high level functions)

Tags: r, haskell

Is there something like a function composition in R?

I think in haskell it's somthing like "(.)" and in agda it's the ring operator.

Also, I find litte information on high level functional programming in R.
I found the Functions "Reduce", "Map", "Filter"..., are there more? Any pointers?

Comment: To get some really useful pointers on functional programming, have a look at this answer to a previous question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874867/learning-functional-programming-with-r/4887648#4887648

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may make compositing function like this:

```
composite<-function(f,g) function(...) f(g(...))

f<-function(x) x+1;
g<-function(x) x*2;
composite(f,g)(7)
composite(g,f)(7)
```

or make operator of this.

About the second point, there are lots of such; I think the most used are the *apply family (sapply, mapply, tapply, lapply, apply...).

Comment: hi. thank you for the answer. one more question that bugs me is: how I could use "f" as a shortcut for "function"? so like "g <- f(x) x*x" for function definitions.

Comment: @mrsteve: not (with a lot of hacking away that is). Seems like a very bad idea to me anyway.

Comment: @mrsteve Unfortunately not -- this is the only keyword in R and, ***, 8 letters. On the other hand, lambda would repel "normal people" and f would be confusing...

Comment: I think many people would want to call their variables lambda when they are doing statistics. You could try to tell them not to but they won’t care. Therefore that’s a reason for it to not be a reserved word

Comment: @mrsteve as of R 4.1.0 `/` is shorthand for `function`, i.e. `/(x) x* x`  is now possible.

Comment: @MarkHeckmann I think you mean backslash ``\`` `\(x) x*x`

Comment: @BenBolker: Uups. Yes, thanks. Mental note: Never make SO comments from a mobile phone :D

Answer (score 20):

The `functional` package has a `Compose` functional which generalizes to any number of functions:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- matrix(runif(100), 10, 10)
mean(rowSums(scale(x)))
# [1] 5.486063e-18

library(functional)
Compose(scale, rowSums, mean)(x)
# [1] 5.486063e-18
```

(Note that the functions are applied from left to right.)

Answer (score 3):

There is now a **compose** function in the **purrr** library. By default composition is made from right to left, as in Haskell, but it can be reversed with the .dir param:

```
library(purrr)
f = function(x) x+1
g = function(x) x*3

> compose(g,f)(1)
[1] 6
> compose(f,g, .dir="forward")(1)
[1] 6
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to provide an answer to question #1. It is possible to define a R composition operator `%.%` that

- allows partial argument assignment to the component functions;
- ensure environment sensitive functions like `ls` act normally.
- the composition body show the actual component function names.

The operator is inspired by the R4.1 `pipeOp` operator `|>`. Here is the intended results:

```
## example component functions
ff <- function(n, a=1.0) 1:n*a
gg <- function(x, b=0.5) x^b
hh <- function(x, c=2.0, d=0.5) d * log(x, c)

## composition #1, rotate `c` in hh()
(tmp <- ff(a=1) %.% gg(b=2) %.% hh(x=3, d=1) %.% round(digits=3))
#' function (...)
#' round(hh(gg(ff(..., a = 1), b = 2), x = 3, d = 1), digits = 3)
tmp(9)
#' [1]   Inf 0.792 0.500 0.396 0.341 0.307 0.282 0.264 0.250

## composition #3: a component function is environment sensitive.
(ls() %.% grep(pattern="^[a-z]", value=TRUE) %.% toupper)(environment())
#' [1] "FF"  "GG"  "HH"  "TMP"
```

Here is the definition of `%.%`:

```
"%.%" <- function(f, g, .dp=0)
{
    f <- substitute(f)
    g <- substitute(g)

    ## treatment of f()
    if("%.%" == all.names(f)[1])
    {
        ## f() is a %.% expression, expand it by a deeper call of %.%.
        f <- eval(as.call(append(as.list(f), c(.dp=.dp+1))))
    }
    else
    {
        ## f() is the deepest function, (i.e., the left most syntax of
        ## a %.% chain), insert ... as its first argument.
        f <- as.call(append(as.list(f), quote(...), 1L))
    }

    ## expands g() to g(f(...)) by treating f(...) as the 1st argument
    g <- as.call(append(as.list(g), f, 1L))

    ## pack up and return
    if(.dp > 0)
    {
        ret <- g # a deeper call of %.% return expanded expression
    }
    else
    {
        ## the top call of %.% build a function enclosing g(f(...))
        ret <- function(...) {}
        body(ret) <- g
        ## treat the function as if it was defined from outside.
        environment(ret) <- parent.frame()
    }
    ret
}

## example component functions
ff <- function(n, a=1.0) 1:n*a
gg <- function(x, b=0.5) x^b
hh <- function(x, c=2.0, d=0.5) d * log(x, c)

## composition #1, rotate `c` in hh()
(tmp <- ff(a=1) %.% gg(b=2) %.% hh(x=3, d=1) %.% round(digits=3))
#' function (...)
#' round(hh(gg(ff(..., a = 1), b = 2), x = 3, d = 1), digits = 3)
tmp(9)
#' [1]   Inf 0.792 0.500 0.396 0.341 0.307 0.282 0.264 0.250

## composition #2: rotate `x` in hh(); compose an anonymous function.
sapply(1:4, ff(a=1) %.% gg(b=2) %.% hh(d=1, c=2) %.% round(digits=3))
#' [[1]]
#' [1] 0
#'
#' [[2]]
#' [1] 0 2
#'
#' [[3]]
#' [1] 0.00 2.00 3.17
#'
#' [[4]]
#' [1] 0.00 2.00 3.17 4.00

## composition #3: a component function is environment sensitive.
(ls() %.% grep(pattern="^[a-z]", value=TRUE) %.% toupper)(environment())
#' [1] "FF"  "GG"  "HH"  "TMP"
## does not show `f`, `g` and `ret` (and `.dp`) as if the composition
## is outside of `%.%`'s environment.

## composition #4: example from Answer #1 by [flodel]
set.seed(123)
x <- matrix(runif(100), 10, 10)
mean(rowSums(scale(x)))
# [1] 5.486063e-18
(scale %.% rowSums %.% mean)(x)
# [1] 5.486063e-18
```

For now I could not get empty argument list to work for functions that tolerated blank argument with `missing` syntax in the function body, so I have to pass `environment()` as an argument to the composition of `ls` and `grep` (example #3), despite `ls` allowing empty argument.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here is a one-liner in base R (>= 4.1.0) using `Reduce` to compose any number of functions, here `scale`, `rowSums` and `mean`.

```
mean(rowSums(scale(mtcars)))      # nested function call

f <- Reduce(\(g, h) {\(x) h(g(x))}, list(scale, rowSums, mean))
f(mtcars)     # now, calling f gives same result as nested call above
```

This is more or less what `functional::Compose` does.

**Notes**:

- `\` is shorthand for `function` as of R 4.1.0
- The solutions that already have been provided are IMO preferable. For example, `purrr::compose` is more readable and flexible and does much more under the hood.