# A function within a function in the R language

Tags: r, function, nested

I have a simple function in the R language, for instance:

```
f<-function(x){
y=(x+2)/3
return(y)
}
```

I want to evaluate this function five times on its own outputs, i.e., `y1=f(x), y2=f(f(x)), y3=f(f(f(x))), y4=f(f(f(f(x)))), y5=f(f(f(f(f(x)))))`.
Is there a simpler way to do it in the form of one function, for instance the function with two arguments when the first argument is `x` and the second argument is the number of evaluation times, i.e., `n`. For instance, for `x=3` and `n=5` I would like to have the function `f2<-(x=3,n=5)` whose output would be in the form of a vector or a list of the length equal to `n` with the values:

```
y1=f(3)=1.666667
y2=f(f(3))=1.222222
y3=f(f(f(3)))=1.074074
y4=f(f(f(f(3))))=1.024691
y5=f(f(f(f(f(3)))))=1.00823
```

How to write such one function in the R ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918819/function-composition-in-r-and-high-level-functions) in another post, just use `Reduce` to create the composition, `g`.

```
composite <- function(g, h) {function(...)g(h(...))}
g <- Reduce(composite, list(f, f, f, f, f))

g(2)
f(f(f(f(f(2)))))

identical(g(2), f(f(f(f(f(2))))))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Using `replicate(5, f)` to create the list of the function replicated would make this a bit more easily extendable.

Comment: @Dason Right, thanks, I hadn't thought of that. I had tried `rep(f, 5)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a helper function like:

```
iterate <- function(f,s,n){
  iterates <- vector(length = n+1)
  iterates[1] <- s
  for(i in 1:n){
    iterates[i+1] <- f(iterates[i])
  }
  iterates
}
```

Then, for example,

```
> iterate(function(x){(x+2)/3},3,5)
[1] 3.000000 1.666667 1.222222 1.074074 1.024691 1.008230
```

You can of course modify the above code so that the vector would start with `f(s)` rather than `s`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also tweak your original function like below:

```r
f2<-function(x, steps){
             ans<-c(x)
              for (i in 1:steps) {
                   y=(x+2)/3
                   ans=append(ans,y)
                   x = y
  }
    return(ans)
}

f2(3,5)
#> [1] 3.000000 1.666667 1.222222 1.074074 1.024691 1.008230
```

Answer (score 1):

`Reduce` will do this if you add a "junk" argument to your `f`. If you just want the last result set `accumulate = F` or just remove the `accumulate` argument from the function

```
f<-function(x, junk){
y=(x+2)/3
return(y)
}

Reduce(f, x = numeric(5), init = 3, accumulate = T)
# [1] 3.000000 1.666667 1.222222 1.074074 1.024691 1.008230
```

Or with `purrr`

```
purrr::accumulate(numeric(5), f, .init = 3)
# [1] 3.000000 1.666667 1.222222 1.074074 1.024691 1.008230
```