# Defining a function as the solution to an implicit equation in R

Tags: r, function, implicit

I have two maps f(i) and w(k). I want to define a function i=i(k) as the implicit solution to f(i)=w(k) in R. Note that k and i are both variables and that there is not necessarily an analytical solution.

How can this be achieved?

So far I have tried uniroot, however, it seems that uniroot is not the suitable command as it is rather intended to find zeros.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You want both a function *and* a variable called `i`?  Note that `uniroot` can be used to solve your sort of problem by noting that f(i) = w(k) can be rewritten as f(i) - w(k) = 0.  Some concrete implementation details would be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand if you want something like the following.
In the code example,

- `i = i(k)`;
- `w(k)` is a function of `k`;
- `f(i) = f(i(k))`.

Function `composite` comes from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918819/function-composition-in-r-and-high-level-functions).
Function `implicit` returns a function.

```
composite <- function(f, g) function(...) f(g(...))
implicit <- function(f, g) function(x) f(x) - g(x)

i <- function(k) sin(k)
w <- function(k) k^2 - 1
f <- function(i) 2*i + 1

fw <- implicit(composite(f, i), w)

fw(1:10)
```