# How to nest a list of functions?

Tags: r

I have a list of functions.

```
fn=list(
  function(x) { ... }
  , function(x) { ... }
  , ...
)
```

I want to generate a nested function of these functions.

```
fn[[1]](fn[[2]](fn[[3]](...(fn[[m]](x))))) # Suppose there are m functions in the list.
```

Is there an easy way to composite these individual function as a nested function?

Answer (score 2):

Another Base R approach:

```
fun <- function(x) Reduce(function(y, f)f(y), fn, init = x)
fun(1:10)
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Comment: Which one is more efficient? The base R approach or the purrr approach?

Answer (score 1):

With `purrr::compose` you could do:

```r
fn <- list(function(x) x^2, sqrt, function(x) x + 2)

fn_compose <- purrr::compose(!!!fn)

fn_compose(c(1:10))
#>  [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, use the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4919319/8245406) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918819/function-composition-in-r-and-high-level-functions).

```r
composite <- function(f,g) function(...) f(g(...))
fn <- list(function(x) x^2, sqrt, function(x) x + 2)
f <- Reduce(composite, fn)

f(1:10)
#>  [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>